# Shell script interpretation

Tags: bash, shell, networking

I am new to shell scripting. I am trying to find what the function is doing. kindly help me deciphering the same. It is not possible to give description of every variable.Just a basic explanation would do. I have problems with the syntax of shell

```
 pgm_lan_interface_mac(){
    if [ $is_lxc -eq 1 ]; then
        return
    fi
    if [ "$1" == 0 ]; then
        return
    fi
    if [ -z "$virtual_mac" ]; then
        return
    fi
    while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
    do
        lan=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
        eth=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'`
        # Let HA interface have its own mac
        if [ "$eth" == "$ha_intf" ]; then
            continue
        fi
        ethN=`echo $eth | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'`
        ethNhex=`printf "%02x" $ethN`
        vmac=`echo ${virtual_mac::15}$ethNhex`
        if [ ! -z "$VIRTUAL_EDGE" ];
        then
            ifconfig $eth down
        fi
        ifconfig $eth hw ether $vmac
        pgm_sub_interface_mac 1 $eth $vmac
        if [ ! -z "$VIRTUAL_EDGE" ];
        then
            ifconfig $eth up
        fi
        log_ha "[$?]: $eth $vmac"
    done < /tmp/ha/lanlinks
}
```

Comment: u want the description of entire function or some specifics?

Comment: Entire function if possible

Comment: For what it's worth, http://shellcheck.net/ points out a large number of problems with this function, and that's not even trying to address the clumsiness of splitting the line manually when `read` could trivially do that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if [ $is_lxc -eq 1 ]; then
    return
fi
```

just comparing if the variable is equal to 1 in that case the function will return nothing and exit

```
if [ "$1" == 0 ]; then
    return
```

here its comparing if the first argument that is passed on to the function if that is 0 then it returns empty

```
if [ -z "$virtual_mac" ]; then
    return
fi
```

this is looking at if the variable virtual_mac is empty, it will return

```
while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
```

in the first part its asking for an input for the variable line and || operator means if the first command executes that is the variable line receives input the command after || will not execute
this part will keep asking for inputs

```
lan=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
```

this defines a variable that is the first word in the initial variable line, awk '{print $1}' prints first word in a line eg. if line = abc xyz

awk '{print $1}' will give abc
awk '{print $2}' will give xyz

```
if [ "$eth" == "$ha_intf" ]; then
    continue
fi
```

again comparing the variable eth with another variable and if they are equal it will continue.

```
ethN=`echo $eth | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'`
```

new variable we are creating from the variable eth , what sed is doing is taking each non-numeric charater of the interface name and removing it so `ethN` is converted to `N` (where `N` is a number, e.g. `eth8` becomes `8`).

```
vmac=`echo ${virtual_mac::15}$ethNhex`
```

here we are creating a variable from two variables virtual_mac and ethNhex. `${virtual_mac::15}` returns the first 15 characters in the value of the ${virtualmac} variable (or the whole thing if there are fewer than 15 chars in the value)

```
 if [ ! -z "$VIRTUAL_EDGE" ];
    then
        ifconfig $eth down
 fi
```

here we are checking if the variable virtual_edge is empty and if it is empty we are looking for a device I guess.

```
pgm_sub_interface_mac 1 $eth $vmac
```

here we are calling another function with 3 arguments as input 2 of the arguments are variables generated in the host function.

```
if [ ! -z "$VIRTUAL_EDGE" ];
```

here again we are checking if the variable virtual edge is empty if it is empty then the following command will execute

```
log_ha "[$?]: $eth $vmac"
```

this is calling another function with the single argument that is made from 3 variables $? means the last value of the exit status of the last function call.

Comment: The `log_ha` line won't do what you expect - if $VIRTUAL_EDGE is empty, $? will be 0, but if $VIRTUAL_EDGE is not empty, it will be the result of the `ifconfig` command. If you want to log the reuslt of a specific command, save that result in a variable (e.g. `RC=$?`) on the line *immediately* after the command. Don't even have an `echo` or an `if` test. You can then use $RC later in the script for tests and log messages.

Comment: Thanks making edits